# Mysql Command line not working on mac

Tags: mysql, mamp

When I try to access mysql command line on my mac it gives me this error - it doesn't matter what mysql command, username, password, server or I use either:

Launch of "mysql" failed: the PowerPC architecture is no longer supported.

This happened right after I installed Mac OS X lion. I am using MAMP Pro - I am upgraded to the latest version: 2.0.3- as my stack and I was wondering if anyone had any solutions for me. This is kind of a priority since I need it to handle large mysql imports.

BTW, I don't have a powerpc. I have intel core duo 2.66ghz

Comment: MySQL has an [EOL](http://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html) for OS X on the PowerPC platform.

Comment: I got it working by using this command: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and reinstalling MySQL from http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/. Depending on your machine, you'll want to either grab the Mac OS X ver. 10.6 (x86, 64-bit) or Mac OS X ver. 10.6 (x86, 32-bit) version.

Comment: Will installing a new version of MySQL affect MAMP at all?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should install another version of mysql or you can install xampp at

> http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-macosx.html

Comment: Will installing a new version of MySQL affect MAMP at all?

Comment: Is http://www.mamp.info/ the MAMP you're referring to? If so, I'm not sure, as I've never used it to install before. Sorry.